# GZIP compression not working- htaccess file might be wrong?

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, gzip

I am having the worst time getting my server to compress my files. I am using ipage as my host, which is running apache II. When I look at the 'headers' area in google developer tools, it says that the file 'accept-encoding':gzip, deflate, sdch', but pagespeed insights is still telling me that my files are not gzipped. Here is my htaccess file code :

this might help too: http://www.uniconutrition.com/info.php

Please help!

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^uniconutrition.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.uniconutrition.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
      RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>

  # Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types
  <IfModule mod_filter.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
                                  application/javascript \
                                  application/json \
                                  application/rss+xml \
                                  application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
                                  application/x-font-ttf \
                                  application/xhtml+xml \
                                  application/xml \
                                  font/opentype \
                                  image/svg+xml \
                                  image/x-icon \
                                  text/css \
                                  text/html \
                                  text/plain \
                                  text/x-component \
                                  text/xml
  </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a small file named info.php, input "phpinfo()" and check if ZLib is included.

This bit usually works for me:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        php_flag zlib.output_compression 1
        php_value zlib.output_compression_level 7
    </IfModule>

    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css application/json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml application/xml text/x-component

    <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg)$" >
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

**Aditionally**, notice that I don't have all your mimetypes included. :) I'm not sure about the blackslashes to use as a delimiter/spacer.

Comment: http://www.uniconutrition.com/info.php   i see a zlib section ..it says enabled...ill try your code :)

Answer (score 1):

Check you're not going through a proxy that's un-gzipping the content on the way down?

I just checked the URL you provided with cURL (with no proxy) and it is showing as gzip'ed when requested as such for HTML at least:

```
$ curl -I -H"Accept-Encoding: gzip" http://www.uniconutrition.com/info.php
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 19 Jul 2013 14:54:15 GMT
Server: Apache/2
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
```

However, CSS and JS are not, e.g. http://www.uniconutrition.com/java/main.js and http://www.uniconutrition.com/css/bootstrap.css

I suspect that your webserver is using [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html) as opposed to mod_filter. Also worth noting that in your example, you're using the wrong mimetype for JS, should be `application/x-javascript` as opposed to `application/javascript`.

As such, you should probably add a (simpler) directive like the following:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript
</IfModule>
```

**EDIT:**

Having had another look, your rewrite rule isn't working either; it specifies that all traffic should be redirected to www.uniconutrition.com, however this isn't happening, so it stands to reason that the rest of the htaccess file is being ignore too. Check with your host.

Comment: i have this in htaccess for redirects- is it contributing to the problem? Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^uniconutrition.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.uniconutrition.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

Comment: Unlikely as that's a redirect rule.

Comment: this is a rookie question- but i cant seem to open any of my files in the browser using the 'http://' before it...so i think this means you are right? How do i troubleshoot this?

Comment: the http:// just gets removed- i think that is the result of a proxy as you mentioned?

Comment: What's the purpose of your redirect rule? It looks kind of useless on second glance (redirect everything where the hostname starts with uniconutrition.com to uniconutrition.com), which would imply that your host doesn't respect htaccess files at all

Comment: I expect your browser is removing (rather, not displaying) the `http://` - Chrome and Firefox at least do this by default unless it's over https

Comment: Disregard my last on the rewrite rule, the one in your question is perfectly fine (redirect all users to www.)

Comment: is it possible i don't have mod_filter enabled or something?